# Cmake executable with auto-generated sources

Tags: c++, cmake

I want to make an executable from, for example, test_runner.cpp:

```
add_executable(myexe ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/test_runner.cpp)
```

But this particular cpp file is itself auto-generated in a pre-build command:

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET myexe PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND deps/cxxtest-4.4/bin/cxxtestgen --error-printer -o "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/test_runner.cpp" src/My_test_suite.h
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
)
```

But now I can't generate new cmake build files because it complains about the missing source, which is indeed missing until pre-build.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The crux of the issue is to apply the [`GENERATED` property](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/prop_sf/GENERATED.html) to "test_runner.cpp".  This tells CMake not to check for its existence at configure time, since it gets created as part of the build process.

You can apply this property manually (e.g. using `set_source_files_properties`).  However, the proper way to handle this is to use the other form of [`add_custom_command`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/add_custom_command.html), i.e. `add_custom_command(OUTPUT ...)` rather than `add_custom_command(TARGET ...)`.

If you specify "test_runner.cpp" as the output of the `add_custom_command(OUTPUT ...)` call, then any target consuming it (in this case "myexe") will cause the custom command to be invoked before that target is built.

So you really only need to change your code to something like:

```
set(TestRunner "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/test_runner.cpp")
add_executable(myexe ${TestRunner})
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${TestRunner}
    COMMAND deps/cxxtest-4.4/bin/cxxtestgen --error-printer -o "${TestRunner}" src/My_test_suite.h
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
)
```

Comment: That was perfect. Thank you. I'm discovering that cmake is more exhaustive and nuanced than it first appears, and I definitely need to read its documentation cover to cover. But it'll be worth it in the end 'cause cmake is so ridiculously damn useful.

Comment: If the used generated files are generated by another target, don't forget to `add_dependencies(myExe theOtherTargetGeneratingTestRunner)` to ensure the files are available in all cases (and not only by chance) when the compilation begins.

Comment: can the OUTPUT of add_custom_comamnd be regular expression?

Answer (score 2):

In my case the generated file might be re-generated on each build (it captures the current state of the git repo and embeds it into the resulting binaries). Hence the accepted approach does not work. I was able to achieve the necessary behavior with the `BYPRODUCTS` option of the `add_custom_target` command:

```
add_custom_target(gen_revision_info ALL 
  COMMAND gen_revision_info.py --output revision_info.cpp
  BYPRODUCTS revision_info.cpp)

add_library(revision_info revision_info.cpp)
```

Now anyone can link with `revision_info` target and have the latest git info embedded in the binaries.