# CMake, how to add files to executable target that hasn't been created yet

Tags: makefile, compilation, cmake

Suppose there's an executable target and some of it's attached header files are missing.

Those missing headers are auto generated by some script.

So in order to ensure that the script runs prior to the executable target, it's reasonable to create a dedicated target which runs this script and function as a dependency to the executable target.

Thus, every time the executable target runs, the missing file will be available because `add_executable` expect all files to be available.

However, trying to do so in the following manner resulted in failure to find the missing file...

```
add_custom_target(create_a_header)
add_custom_command(TARGET create_a_header POST_BUILD COMMAND /bin/sh create_a_header.sh )

set(SOURCE_FILES a.h a.c)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
add_dependency(${PROJECT_NAME} create_a_header)
```

is there any other option to add files to executable even if they're still not available ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cmake executable with auto-generated sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32512872/cmake-executable-with-auto-generated-sources)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake can handle outputs of [custom commands](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) residing in the same `CMakeLists.txt` directly.

> A target created in the same directory (`CMakeLists.txt` file) that specifies any output of the custom command as a source file is given a rule to generate the file using the command at build time.

So your code should look like this:

```perl
include(FindUnixCommands)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/a.h"
    COMMAND ${BASH} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/create_a_header.sh" 
)

set(
    SOURCE_FILES 
        "a.c"
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/a.h"
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")
```